# Understanding an email with no SPF, DKIM, or DMARC but is has a valid digital signature

Tags: email, digital-signature

Can someone explain in simple terms what does it mean, that an email has no SPF, DKIM, or DMARC (from what I read and understood is that this email is likely to end up as as spam or rejected by the email server, kindly correct if wrong).

What I am trying to understand is how adding a digital signature to such an email be like, would it make this email legit, or allow the email to prove that it's not junk.

The email has a valid digital signature, and thunderbird says the message isnot encrypted.

Comment: A signature _inside_ an email does nothing to verify it's authenticity... It's just extra data at that point. You need to do something to: verify that the original sending host is permitted to send on behalf of that domain (e.g: [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#Implementation)); or prove that the sender has the private key that matches the public key associated with the domain (e.g: [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail#Technical_details)); etc...

Comment: OP did specify "digital signature" in the subject (but not the body) of the question. OP could you please use the EDIT button to make your question more clear? What digital signature, where?